# How to add a ResourceDictionary to MergedDictionaries of the MainWindow in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am using MEF Bootstrapper. One of the plugins I have wants to add a `ResourceDictionary` to `MergedDictionaries` of the `MainWindow`

I have tried this.

Exported IMainWindowView through MEF and imported it into that plugin. Turned out the one Imported through MEF is separate instance, not the one Application is using.

How do I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: is it a separate assembly?

Comment: @mvermef Yes, added through MEF.

Comment: via SelectAssemblies override in CM?